# Alternatives to Stingray Objective Toolkit C++ for 64bit applications?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, toolkit, stingray

We are currently using Stingray Objective Toolkit in our C++ applications for MFC UI controls. We are planning to migrate the application to 64bit and when inquired for a version of stingray toolkit, it was very expensive. I'm not sure of any other toolkits offering 64bit source code. Does anyone have an idea of cheaper alternatives to stingray offering 64-bit support?

Answer (score 0):

Toolkit Pro by CodeJocks...http://www.codejock.com/

I don't know how it compares to Stingray.  The library by CodeJocks is provided with source code and compiles for 32 and 64-bits, and MBCS and Unicode.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if its worth the price difference to spend time on migrating to Codejock or BCGSoft? Has anyone migrated from Stingray to any other toolkits? If so how much time is it going to take?
PS: The cost of stingray is more than twice of Codejock/BCGSoft